# Null chars in input string after sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

In the following code I want to read the first 2 chars in the hex string 'a', convert them into the corresponding byte value with sscanf and put the result in 'b'. No modifications should be performed on 'a'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char a[]="fa23456789abcdef"; // 0-9 a-f
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned int idx = 0;

    for(idx = 0; idx < 16; idx++)
        printf("%c", a[idx]); // raw dump 'a'

    printf("\n");
    sscanf(a, "%2hhx", &b); // do sscanf
    printf("%d\n", b); // check that 'b' has been correctly updated

    for(idx = 0; idx < 16; idx++)
        printf("%c", a[idx]); // raw dump 'a'... again

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
fa23456789abcdef
250
   3456789abcdef
```

Compiler (GNU GCC in Code::Blocks):

```
[...]|14|warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'sscanf' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]|
[...]stdio.h|348|note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'unsigned char *'|
[...]|14|warning: unknown conversion type character 'h' in format [-Wformat]|
[...]|14|warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]|
||=== Build finished: 0 errors, 3 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

In the output the first 3 chars of 'a' are replaced with 3 null chars for no apparent reason. All the warnings are pointing to the sscanf line.
Also, code::blocks for some reason doesn't like the 'h' modifier even if the 'b' value is updated correctly.

Expected result:

```
fa23456789abcdef
250
fa23456789abcdef
```

Can strtol be used alternatively in this case?

Comment: The raw dump of `a` could be just: `printf("%.16s\n", a);` because the 16 limits the output to 16 bytes from the string (so the fact that it is not null terminated won't matter).

Comment: One question: Why is this tagged as C++?

Comment: @Manu343726: it shouldn't be (tagged as a C++ question), and now it isn't.

Comment: You can't really use `strtol()` for this because it might treat the whole string as valid input (and then run into undefined behaviour as it reads beyond the end of `a`), or it might spot that after 8 hex bytes you've reached the limits of your 32-bit `long` and the ninth byte triggers overflow.  You can't tell `strtol()` to use only the first _N_ bytes of the string except by passing a string that is only _N_ bytes long (plus a terminating null byte).

Comment: I've edited your question, changing "NULL chars" to "Null chars". `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant, unrelated to the null character (`'\0'`).

Comment: Actually passing just strings made of _N_ bytes is still ok for what I am doing. So yep, I solved now btw. Also, thanks Keith for the corrections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `sscanf` doesn't support `hh`, which means it's converting as an `unsigned int` and trying to stuff that into an `unsigned char`-sized variable, causing undefined behaviour.  In your case, that means apparently overwriting part of `a`.  Fix your warnings!

If your `sscanf` *did* support `hh`, you'd be fine, but you should probably still change `a` to be a `char` array instead of `unsigned char`.

You need to read your local `sscanf` documentation to figure out what you should be passing, or alternately just change `b` to be `unsigned int` and use `"%2x"` as your format string.

Comment: `%hhx` was added in C99; compiling with `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` (assuming GCC, of course) should/might resolve the warning.

Comment: Cool - OP says GCC/Code::Blocks, so that may work for him.  It must be an old GCC if it doesn't default to C99, though.

Comment: GCC regardless of age defaults to GNUC, which is not the same as any of the ISO standards.

Comment: Yeah, but recent ones default to `gnu99`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `a` should be `char`, not `unsigned char`. With this change, I have the expected behaviour in my computer.

[Here is the sscanf documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)